# Exim: email eximstats -html report

Tags: email, exim

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get work out how to send a html message using exim.

To send a normal text message:

```
$ mail -s "Testing" me@mydomain.com
123

CTRL-D
```

That works fine, but how can I specify `Content-type: text/html`?

My ultimate goal is to be able to do this:

```
$ eximstats -html /var/log/exim4/mainlog | mail -s "Exim report" me@mydomain.com
```

and have it actually arrive as a html email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I settled on, with help from Kondybas:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/log/exim4

cat << HEREFILE | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: root@$( hostname -f)
To: YOUREMAIL@DOMAIN.COM
Subject: Exim Report $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

$(/usr/sbin/eximstats -html mainlog mainlog.1)

HEREFILE
```

Comment: Note: If you just want a plain text report, this functionality is built into debian-exim. Just add your email address to: `/etc/cron.daily/exim4-base`

Answer (score 1):

Universal approach indifferent to the used MTA software is:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat << HEREFILE | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: HTML SENDER <root@$( hostname )>
To: me@domain.tld
Subject: HTML formatted message
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html><body>
  Hello, <B>admin</B>!
</body></html>
HEREFILE
####
```

Even `sendmail -t` command should be untouchable as far as exim/postfix/qmail all mimic sendmail for compatibility with old software.

Comment: That example works well thanks. So if i replace the actual html in your example with `$(eximstats -html /var/log/exim4/mainlog)` I would expect it to email the report, but sendmail just waits for more input. Why? I can't figure it out.

Comment: OK... for some reason sendmail sits there for a few seconds waiting then closes by itself...

Comment: Exim can't wait until your report been generated and close connection on timeout. Do all heavy job before you invoke `exim`

`REPORT=$(eximstats...); cat ... $REPORT ...`

Comment: Also you can replace `exim` invocation by sending to file for further analysis: `cat << HEREFILE > OUTPUT.TXT ....`

Comment: I thought it might be that, so I tried loading eximstats into a variable first but it made no difference. sendmail just pauses for a few seconds after the command before sending in either case.

Comment: Do you notice the empty line between headers and message body? It is mandatory.

Comment: Yes, see my answer below. That still produces the pause for me. How about you?

Comment: How about exim's logs?

Comment: No indication of error. Strange. Anyway, it works.